# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. (M1)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 61, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: stat() failed with errno=25

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/homebrew/bin/tensorboard", line 5, in 
from tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard import main
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 72, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 61, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: stat() failed with errno=25

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Help me gurus please!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please let us know the steps that you have followed to install Tensorflow?